# Intuitive feeling for Convex set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can anyone please give me some insight about convex set 
I am aware of the definition of convex set -
A set $E$,which is a subset of $R^k$ if 
$¶.x + (1-¶).y$ belongs to E whenever x,y belongs to E and $0<¶<1$. 
I am still in the beginning chapters of Rudin,so my knowledge is very basic.

Comment: Specifically, what do you need insight on?

Comment: May be some non trivial examples .

Comment: I am aware that balls and k-cells are convex

Comment: What does the paragraph symbol ¶ represent?

Comment: Simply speaking, a convex set is one that doesn't have caves or cavities.

Comment: [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Convex_polygon_illustration1.svg) vs [nonconvex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Convex_polygon_illustration2.svg)

Answer (score 5):

You can't hide in a convex set. No matter where you are, and no matter where your adversary is, it can see you and you can see it.

In a nonconvex set, on the other hand, it is possible to hide: there are some positions where you and your adversary cannot see each other, because some corner or other obstruction is blocking your view of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively a set is convex if every segment you draw between two points in the set is still in the set.
For example a disk is convex because if you take two points in the disk then the segment that link these two points is still in the disk.